# Finding the coordinates of a point $P$ that divides a line segment into a given ratio.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I need to find the coordinates of the point $P$ that divides a line segment $AB$ into a given ratio $r$. While searching for a quick formula I found two methods and I don't know wich one to use.
The first formula I found it in [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry/hs-geo-analytic-geometry/hs-geo-dividing-segments/v/ratios-of-distances-between-colinear-points) and it's solved like this:

$$P(x_A+r(x_B-x_A), y_A + r(x_B-x_A))$$

And the second method that I found on my math book is:

$$P(\frac{x_A+rx_B}{1+r},\frac{y_A+ry_B}{1+r})$$

But if I use the same example as Khan Academy: $A(-1,4), C(4,-6)$ and $r = 3:5$. Using the first equation gives $B(2,-2)$ but using the second one gives $B(7/8,1/4)$.

My question is, wich one is the right one?

Answer (score 1):

You could check the two answers to see which is right.  Your answer from the Khan Academy formula has $B$ closer to $C$ than $A$, which cannot be right.

They are both right, but use different definitions of $r$.  The Khan Academy is defining $r$ at the fraction of the distance from $A$ to $B$.  You would divide the segment into pieces $\frac 38$ and $\frac 58$ of its length, so you should use $r=\frac 38$, not $r=\frac 35$ in that formula.  The one from your math book is using $r=\frac 35$.  As you used $r=\frac 35$ the second gave the right answer.  You need to look at the definitions of the terms in the formula.

Comment: If I check the ratio from both methods i have $AB/AC=3/5$ for the first one and $AB/AC=3/8$ for the second one

Comment: You should have $AB/AC=3/8$.  You should have $AB/BC=3/5$.  They are two ways of stating the same thing and the formulas reflect them.

Comment: Try it with $(0,0)$ to $(8,0)$ where you know what should happen.

Comment: Why is that I need to have $AB/AC=3/8$? the problem in Khan Academy and its solutions state that should be $3/5$

Comment: When you say divide the segment in the ratio $3:5$ you want the second part to be $\frac 53$ of the first part.  That means the first part is $\frac 38$ of the original segment and the second part is $\frac 58$.  This gives the $3:5$ ratio-look at the numerators.